# Mount Permission denied

Tags: mount

I have an Ubuntu Desktop client machine ( with version 22.04 ) where I have to receive mappings from an RedHat 8.9 server
My RedHat server is configured with Samba to share folder. The export file is populated.
On all other servers it works fine, as they have fix IP address.
I have an Ubutnu client machine where it gives error. Client is confuigured with sssd
When the client starts without the LAN cable connected, it gets an IP from range 10.10.240.X and it receives correclty the shares from the nsf server.
When the client starts with the LAN connected, its gets an IP from range 10.10.130.X but iut doens't receives the shared folders.
I reveive the error:
mount.nfs4: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nsf4: access denbied by server while mounting server:/folder
I already have added on the exports file of my server the insecure option and exporting the fle with exports -rva; but this has not changed
Does anyone has already configured or had to put this configuration in place ?
Thanks for the help